# Generate immutable collection in one expression

Tags: scala

How to fill collection and then add one element to it without using mutable collection or declaring it as `var`?

In other words how I can use immutable collection in the following code instead of mutable.Buffer?

```
 val values: mutable.Buffer[MyClass] = {
    (for (i <- 1 until 10
    ) yield MyClass(Some(i)).toBuffer
  }

  values += MyClass(None)
```

Comment: Mind you, generating data based on the element index is what the `tabulate` method does. For example, `List.tabulate(10)(i => MyClass(Some(i + 1)))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I switched to map, but with for-comprehension this should be the same:

```
val values = (1 until gridSize.size).map(i => MyClass(Some(i))) ++ Seq(MyClass(None), ...)
```

Comment: just for the fun of it, the same with for: 
`val value = (for (i <- (1 until 10).toList) yield MyClass(Some(i))) ::: MyClass(None) :: Nil`